# Android: NullPointerException creating new Intent

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I always get a Nullpointer Exception when creating a new Intent Object.
My intention is to create a new Activity which opens a new View with its "onCreate" method.

This is my Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void activateTimer(){
        // some code ....           
        MyTimer timer = new MyTimer(MainActivity.this);
    }
}
```

This is my Timer Class:

```
public class MyTimer extends MainActivity{
    private Context contextMain;
    public MyTimer(Context context){
        this.contextMain = context;
        // some more code ...
        openMyActivity(contextMain); 
}
public void openMyActivity(Context contextMain){
    // some code ...
    // The next line throws the NPE!
Intent intent = new Intent(contextMain, MyNotificationActivity.class);
this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

My Activity which should be created:

```
public class MyNotificationActivity extends Activity {  
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notification);
 } 
}
```

Here is the error log:

```
03-21 12:47:51.949: W/dalvikvm(2442): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
03-21 12:47:51.959: E/AndroidRuntime(2442): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
03-21 12:47:51.959: E/AndroidRuntime(2442): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 12:47:51.959: E/AndroidRuntime(2442):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
03-21 12:47:51.959: E/AndroidRuntime(2442):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
03-21 12:47:51.959: E/AndroidRuntime(2442):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
03-21 12:47:51.959: E/AndroidRuntime(2442):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
03-21 12:47:51.959: E/AndroidRuntime(2442):     at com.myApp.MyTimer.openNotificationInMain(MyTimer.java:135)
03-21 12:47:51.959: E/AndroidRuntime(2442):     at com.myApp.MyTimer.prompt(MyTimer.java:80)
03-21 12:47:51.959: E/AndroidRuntime(2442):     at com.myApp.MyTimer$1.run(MyTimer.java:38)
03-21 12:47:51.959: E/AndroidRuntime(2442):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

This is my Manifest.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myApp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.myApp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    
    <activity android:name="com.myApp.MyNotifikationActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:parentActivityName="com.myApp.MainActivity"  >
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.myApp.MainActivity" />            
    </activity>         
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: And when you looked at `com.myApp.MyTimer.openNotificationInMain(MyTimer.java:135)`, which the stack trace clearly identifies, what did you find?

Comment: I guess the line he marked with `// The next line throws the NPE!` comment?

Comment: @donfuxx Which is, of course, *not* the line the stack trace actually identifies.

Comment: Yep, agree on that @JasonC

Comment: I shortened the code to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: Line 135 in MyTimer: 
    this.startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `MyTimer` extends `Activity` but here you're instantiating it yourself:

```
MyTimer timer = new MyTimer(MainActivity.this)
```

Now, when you do this, the activity isn't properly initialized to be used as an activity or a context and all kinds of failures are possible.

Seems like you should remove the `extends Activity` from `MyTimer` altogether and pass in an `Activity` or `Context` argument to those methods that need it. For example,

```
public void openMyActivity(Activity act) {
  // ...
  act.startActivityForResult(...);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I removed the "extends Activity" but how can I use the "this.startActivity(intent);" as my MyTimer class now is no Activity any more?

Comment: @user3445825 Updated the answer with a specific example

Answer (score 0):

Why do you extend Mytimer to MainActivity?. I don't see the need of that

change it to ....

```
public class MyTimer{
private Context contextMain;
   public MyTimer(Context context){
    this.contextMain = context;
    // some more code ...
    openMyActivity(contextMain); 
  }
 public void openMyActivity(Context contextMain){
// some code ...
// The next line throws the NPE!
Intent intent = new Intent(contextMain, MyNotificationActivity.class);
this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

}